# Cakephp model->save equivalent in symfony framework without doctrine

Tags: symfony, cakephp

I need the equivalent method in symfony framework which is there cakephp model->save() method , I do not want to use doctrine orm I just need cakephp like solution to my problem

Comment: can i import cakephp functionality into symfony?

Comment: What have you done so far? Post your code.

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for (i.e. `$model->save()`) is called [Active Record](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_record_pattern). `Doctrine` was using it in version 1.x but it does not anymore since version 2.x. You need to find some `ORM` which does and use it in your `Symfony` application. As far as I know you can't use `Cake's` ORM as a standalone component hence you can't inject it in `Symfony` so you need to find some other Active Record `ORM`.

You should give [Propel](http://propelorm.org/) a try (and its integration with `Symfony` - [PropelBundle](https://github.com/propelorm/PropelBundle)
)

Comment: my real problem is I code html forms and give inputs names as per the table columns and in cakephp it was submitting and saving those values easily without any configuration so thats what i needed but even i use orm like propel or doctrine i have to configure entities as per the db table columns so I just want save this work as i am developing so many applications and one more thing I know i can generate such codes using many php generators available but i need use symfony for other features of it

Comment: Symfony does have some crud generation capability: http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SensioGeneratorBundle/commands/generate_doctrine_crud.html which sort of sounds like what you are asking for.

Comment: Re: *As far as I know you can't use Cake's ORM as a standalone component* I think this may have changed as of now: [`cakephp/orm`](https://github.com/cakephp/orm)

Answer (score 0):

You need to take time to approach Symfony2, you just can't look for an equivalent for every single thing. Learning how to do things "the Symfony" way will be worth in the mid/long run, because the logic is different between those 2 frameworks in many places you won't be able to reason like this for long.

A great place to start is the Symfony book: http://symfony.com/doc/current/index.html

Without Doctrine, you don't have the notion of "model". Then you can only fall back to save (array) data manually using PDO.